# How to use the AntiForgeryToken with a custom log-in form?

Tags: security, login, mvc-forms

There may be several forms on any given page of our site. Distinguishing between post requests from these forms is implemented using [**`ValidateRenderingToken`**](http://www.reinoudvandalen.nl/blog/ultimate-fix-for-multiple-forms-on-one-page-with-sitecore-mvc/). There is also [**`AntiForgeryToken` / validation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.antiforgerytoken(v=vs.118).aspx) defined for every form.

One of these forms is the log-in / log-out form in the header. My problem is currently this error when logging in:

```
The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "", but the current user is "extranet\someuser".
```

And this error when logging out (previously logged in as an admin):

```
The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "sitecore\admin", but the current user is "".
```

As I understand, this is because the user is changed in the middle of the request, and the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute for all subsequent post handlers on the page gets called anyway and fails. This is despite having a `[ValidateRenderingToken]` attribute on every POST handler:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateRenderingToken]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(SomeModel model)
{
    // ...
}
```

The only solution that comes to mind is to somehow postpone the login/logout procedure until the end of the request, when all anti-forgery validation has been executed. Is there a better, more standard way of handling the log-in / log-out procedure with multiple secured forms on the page?

Comment: Did you try the 3rd option here in the marked answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970102/anti-forgery-token-is-meant-for-user-but-the-current-user-is-username

Comment: @TamásTárnok yes, and it didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the root of the issue. It was caused by some controller actions, for which:

- Either the `[ValidateRenderingToken]` attribute was missing;
- Or the `[ValidateRenderingToken]` attribute was added *after* the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute, thus changing the execution order.

Comment: Ah, clear. So first it was checking the AntiForgeryToken and then it was checking the form that it was really from that form where you sent the POST. I think you can mark this as answer. It could be really helpful for others.